Add field file for upload inside a custom field
Drupal 9.5.11
I have a Timeline component that uses three fields:

field_title
field_body
field_timeline

Field_timeline is a custom field with:

TimelineDefaultFormatter.php
Timeline.php
TimelineDefaultWidget.php

I tried to add a upload field to add an attachment file.
The UI now shows the upload button but I cannot save the file.
I think the problem is in the definiton of the property
public static function propertyDefinitions(StorageDefinition $storage)
  {
    $properties = [];

    $properties['title'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Title'));

    $properties['summary'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Abstract'));

    $properties['date'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Date'));

    $properties['attenzione'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Attenzione'));

    $properties['allegato'] = DataDefinition::create('entity:file')->setLabel(t('Allegato'));

    return $properties;
  }

I tried file entity:file entity:field_item:file without success, the are always error.
The error is the following
UPDATE with full error stack trace

2024-07-23 08:46:14 [Tue Jul 23 06:46:14.075015 2024] [php:notice] [pid 35] [client 172.22.0.1:35556] Error: Call to a member function isNew() on array in /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Plugin/Validation/Constraint/EntityChangedConstraintValidator.php on line 19 #0 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/Validation/RecursiveContextualValidator.php(201): Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\Validation\Constraint\EntityChangedConstraintValidator->validate(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\Validation\Constraint\EntityChangedConstraint))\n#1 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/Validation/RecursiveContextualValidator.php(153): Drupal\Core\TypedData\Validation\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateConstraints(Array, '0000000000000a5...', Array)\n#2 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/Validation/RecursiveContextualValidator.php(163): Drupal\Core\TypedData\Validation\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateNode(Object(Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityAdapter))\n#3 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/Validation/RecursiveContextualValidator.php(163): Drupal\Core\TypedData\Validation\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateNode(Object(Drupal\timeline\Plugin\Field\FieldType\Timeline))\n#4 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/Validation/RecursiveContextualValidator.php(163): Drupal\Core\TypedData\Validation\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateNode(Object(Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList))\n#5 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/Validation/RecursiveContextualValidator.php(105): Drupal\Core\TypedData\Validation\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateNode(Object(Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityAdapter), Array, true)\n#6 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/Validation/RecursiveValidator.php(93): Drupal\Core\TypedData\Validation\RecursiveContextualValidator->validate(Object(Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityAdapter), NULL, NULL)\n#7 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/TypedData.php(132): Drupal\Core\TypedData\Validation\RecursiveValidator->validate(Object(Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityAdapter))\n#8 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php(489): Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedData->validate()\n#9 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Entity/EntityFormDisplay.php(248): Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->validate()\n#10 /opt/drupal/web/modules/contrib/inline_entity_form/src/Form/EntityInlineForm.php(256): Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityFormDisplay->validateFormValues(Object(Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph), Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))\n#11 /opt/drupal/web/modules/contrib/inline_entity_form/src/Element/InlineEntityForm.php(167): Drupal\inline_entity_form\Form\EntityInlineForm->entityFormValidate(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))\n#12 [internal function]: Drupal\inline_entity_form\Element\InlineEntityForm::validateEntityForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState), Array)\n#13 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormValidator.php(282): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#14 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormValidator.php(238): Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))\n#15 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormValidator.php(238): Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))\n#16 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormValidator.php(238): Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))\n#17 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormValidator.php(238): Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))\n#18 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormValidator.php(238): Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))\n#19 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormValidator.php(238): Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))\n#20 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormValidator.php(118): Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState), 'node_unipv_come...')\n#21 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(593): Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->validateForm('node_unipv_come...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))\n#22 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(325): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('node_unipv_come...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))\n#23 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/FormController.php(73): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object(Drupal\node\NodeForm), Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))\n#24 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch))\n#25 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#26 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(580): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()\n#27 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(121): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))\n#28 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array)\n#29 /opt/drupal/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(169): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()\n#30 /opt/drupal/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(81): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)\n#31 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(58): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)\n#32 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(48): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)\n#33 /opt/drupal/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)\n#34 /opt/drupal/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)\n#35 /opt/drupal/vendor/asm89/stack-cors/src/Asm89/Stack/Cors.php(49): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)\n#36 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(48): Asm89\Stack\Cors->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)\n#37 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(51): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)\n#38 /opt/drupal/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)\n#39 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(718): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)\n#40 /opt/drupal/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))\n#41 {main}, referer: http://localhost/node/36/edit
Can someone help me in the configuration?


What was the error?

The error information belongs in the Question rather than in a comment.

You should get the stack trace also.
